# Formatting background notifications with notifee

Tags: android, firebase, react-native, push-notification

Is it possible to format the notification received when app is in background or in quit state?

Firebase messaging displays the notification as it is i.e. as a json string, and does not hit any of the background handlers, it gets directly displayed in system tray.

So basically we want to receive a notification payload body field as notification json format it to string and display with help of notifee.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can formate the received notification.
for that you need to send only data in payload and set "content_available" : true,
"priority": "high" just like the below payload
{
"to":"Device_token",
"data": {
"title": "JSON.stringify(owner)",
"body": "JSON.stringify(user)",
"picture": "JSON.stringify(picture)"
},
"content_available" : true,
"priority": "high"
}
when receive on device parse it according to your need